# Ubuntu 20.04, switch between two keyboard layouts does not work properly

Tags: keyboard, input, layout

on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation, i'm currently facing the issue that i can't switch between two keyboard layouts with the shortcut super + space.

I use a Duck2 mini with QWERTY layout, ubuntu system language is English (US) and also the first (main) input source. After i switch to any other language using the shortcut, the indicator on the gnome bar and also the popup in the middle of the screen shows that the layout has switched, but i can't use the layout or any of the characters from the second language.

I found out that if i delete the second input source and "reinstall" / add it to my input sources, i can switch properly and use the layout.

Unfortunately i don't know what kind of output would be helpful durig the troubleshooting process, so feel free to let me know what you folks need.

Thank's in advance.

Regards

Comment: It has happened for me too without coming back from suspend.
I just changed from laptop keyboard to a wireless USB keyboard and keyboard layout change stopped working!
By the way, Gnome shell session restart worked quickly.

Comment: Is there an official ticket for this bug ?

Answer (score 7):

You haven't asked any concrete question, it rather looks like a bug report. Though to help and add something beneficial, I confirm I'm also affected by the same buggy experience and other observations and a workaround:

- the issue happens after resuming from the suspended state. I'm not sure if it's the only thing causing the issue
- reinstalling the language input sources works, but is very uncomfortable
- I found restarting the Gnome Shell session by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> the quickest workaround to fix the issue

Comment: This doesnt work for cinnamon

Answer (score 6):

I experience the same issues. The keyboard layout gets stuck on my German layout often after suspend or after the computer has been running for while.
What helps me to get out of this state is to open the `Region & Language` settings dialog and reorder any of the input sources. After that I can switch between input sources again. At least until it gets stuck the next time.

Comment: I also add addtional language switching option like Caps, and after the save it work. What puzzles me though, is what fails....

Answer (score 0):

I am exactly in the same situation as described by sbocinec. Restarting Gnome Shell reinstates the layout switching keyboard shortcuts.

You can also set the keyboard shortcut by going to

Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Typing
and define shortcuts for Switch to next/previous input source. This shortcut is not affected by resumption from the suspended state.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your gnome shell with

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

from the terminal.